# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence cannot be found with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm praticing with JPA API. I got an error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence cannot be found
```

My code below:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf;
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mail");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Version v");
List<Version> versions = query.getResultList();
```

The error at line `emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mail");`

Any solution?

Comment: check if all required jars are in classpath.

Comment: `Persistence` and `EntityManagerFactory` normally are provided by the same jar (e.g. javaee-api-7.0.jar), can you tell us which one you are using?

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using? Are you running standalone or in a (JEE) container? If standalone, compare the (runtime) classpath to your build path to find missing .jars in the classpath.

Comment: OK. I missed `javax.persistence.jar` in my classpath. Added and problem solved now. Thanks you.

Answer (score 31):

You are trying to set up a standalone JPA project. In order to do so you need a JPA provider jars. The two more popular providers are Eclipselink and Hibernate. If you are using maven you can add dependencies to their implementations.

- For Eclipselink

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- For Hibernate

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

If you are not using maven you can download their implementations from their sites and put it in your classpath.

- For Eclipselink: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/
- For Hibernate: http://hibernate.org/orm/

Some JPA quickstarts are recommending to add only the JPA API (interface declarations only) dependencies with maven.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

or

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

This approach will be successful only in server environment as the server will provide appropriate implementation at runtime.

Comment: Thanks you. The problem is I missed `javax.persistence.jar` in my classpath.

Comment: hibernate-core is needed

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Search "Deployment Assembly" -> Add Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

if using maven , add below dependency in Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then clean install maven