# JPA Persistence class workaround

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using EclipseLink as the JPA provider but on calling:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("emfactory1")
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

The `pom.xml` file reads as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

On looking around I found [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639515/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-persistence-cannot-be-found) to fetch only the JPA API:

```
<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
```

But that still gives me the same exception. Suffice to say I'm now stranded and in need of assistance.

Edit

Here's a screenshot of the output
[image: output]

Comment: can you show us how you create `Persistence` ?

Comment: @YCF_L  not sure i understand your question but i've used the class to get an instance of the EntityManagerFactory

Comment: did you import `import javax.persistence.Persistence;` in your class?

Comment: yes. I've already included the import

Comment: can you please check the name of `persistence-unit` in `persistance.xml`, you should to find `emfactory1`

Comment: the argument `emfactory1` should be the `name` attribute  provided in the `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: How are you *running* this program?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've created a `main` function which calls the class methods where I've implemented the `EntityManager` logic

Comment: @YCF_L this is exception at runtime, so compilation (and import) assume is good,

Comment: Are you running it from command line? The essence is: are you actually including the dependencies *at runtime*? You can try the [exec maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html).

Comment: I'm basically letting the IDE do most of the work for me

Comment: i assume this is a problem of maven and not of jpa, so can you please share the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason of Error**: Data source is missing in your code.

Try this.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(DATA_SOURCE_NAME);

                        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
                        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE, ds);
                        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                                PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, properties);
```